# How to make rows' height in grid properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, alignment

Recently I have added new rows to my template and everything seemed to be good to me, but for some reason my hidden panel started to behave awkwardly. The panel should be in the center. It appears after animation.
I noticed problems start after adding RowDefinition Height="40"/>, but I don't understand exactly what is wrong and how it should be instead. Please help me.

```
   <Grid Margin="0,80,0,0" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="40" Margin="0,10,0,10" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Controller.LegViewModel.Title}" FontSize="28"/>
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Controller.LegViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,10,0,10" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LegTemplateSelector}" Background="#FFF7F7F7"/>
        <ListView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Controller.LegViewModel.LegSections}" Margin="5,10,5,10" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LegTemplateSelector}" Background="#FFF7F7F7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>-->
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource StandartPartTemplate}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <!--<ContentControl ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LegTemplateSelector}" Background="#FFF7F7F7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>-->
        </ListView>
        <!--<ContentControl Content="{Binding Controller.LegViewModel}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource LegTemplateSelector}" Background="#FFF7F7F7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>-->

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="AddButton" Command="{Binding RevertCommand}" Content="Вернуться к ноге" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="408" Background="#FFDBEDF7" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddButton_Copy" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Сохранить" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="408" Background="#FFDBEDF7" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Button x:Name="AddButton2" Content="Сохранить" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="408" Background="#FFDBEDF7" FontSize="16" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Border Visibility="{Binding PanelOpened, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" x:Name="ShadowOverlay">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.78"/>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>

        <Border x:Name="panelControl" Margin="0,0,-450,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="450" Height="275" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPanelViewModel}" >
            <Border.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Border.RenderTransform>

            <Grid>
                <Canvas Background="#FFC6E8E6">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="135" FontSize="14" Canvas.Top="4"><Run Text="Добавить сво"/><Run Text="ё описание"/><Run Text=" "/><Run Text=" "/></TextBlock>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Text1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="61" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="43" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=Text2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="173"/>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="есть поле для размерности" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding Path=HasSize}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="109"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Dimentions}" Visibility="{Binding Path=HasSize, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Canvas.Left="199" Canvas.Top="113" Height="23"/>
                    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Отмена" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Canvas.Left="53" Canvas.Top="232"/>
                    <Button x:Name="button_Copy" Content="Добавить" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" Canvas.Left="249" Canvas.Top="232"/>
                    <Separator Height="18" Margin="0" Canvas.Top="19" Width="442"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Top="37" Canvas.Left="10" Text="Первая часть:"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock_Copy1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Top="152" Canvas.Left="10"><Run Text="Вторая часть "/><Run Text="(не обязательно к заполнению):"/></TextBlock>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_Copy" Content="двойная размерность (х*х)" Visibility="{Binding Path=DoubleSizeAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsChecked="{Binding HasSize}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="132"/>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="AddButton2">
                <BeginStoryboard Name="MyBeginStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" local1:StoryboardHelper.CompletedCommand="{Binding Path=OpenPanelCommand}">
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="panelControl" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"
                            Duration="0:0:005" From="0" To="-700" />

                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
```

[Before animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpjOC.jpg)

[After animation, before I added new rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi5l8.jpg)

[After animation, with added rows 0 and 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbZd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "panel" (the border named panelControl) is a child of the Grid for which you are creating new rows.

If you do not say in which row a child of a Grid is, the default row the child will be in is the first row (index 0). The same is true if we are talking about a Grid's column. In your case, your first row is the one with Height of 40. The Margin of the child control will be relative to that cell (column 0, row 0)

If you want your child to occupy all the available space, just set the its RowSpan, like so:

```
<Border x:Name="panelControl" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,0,-450,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="450" Height="275" DataContext="{Binding CurrentPanelViewModel}" >
```

Alternatively, you could just put both your Grid and your Border inside another Grid with 1 row and 1 column. This way both your original Grid and your Border named "panelControl" are on top of each other.

```
<Grid> //This is your new Grid
    <Grid> //This is your original grid
    ....
    </Grid>
    <Border x:Name="panelControl" .../> //This is your Border
</Grid>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!